# What are some enterprise level linux distributions

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

I've been trying to get a comprehensive list of enterprise linux distributions but all I can find is Red Hat.

Also, does such a thing truly exist or is Red Hat an anomaly. Surely once a distro becomes more and more mission critical, we're into global unix suppliers e.g. IBM (AIX) & Oracle (Solaris).

Comment: SLES and partially oracle linux though some may say it is a rhel clone

Comment: This really depends what you mean by "enterprise linux distributions", which is quite a subjective term. If you mean offering paid-for-support then there's RHEL but also SUSE Enterprise (and probably some more). You can also, of course, get paid support for most flavours of Linux but not from the vendor, from a third party. I would argue that just because something is missing critical is no reason to go AIX or Solaris; just because you have paid a lot for it doesn't mean it'll work any better with your setup or support will be any quicker than a free commercially supported OS.

Comment: Besides the fact that "enterprise level" is completely arbitrary, making a list of them isn't really what we do; we're looking for specific questions or problems you're running into trying to use Linux

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean distributions that have extended support life cycles (which could be a subjective definition in and of itself)? If that's your definition, [SUSE Enterprise Linux](https://www.suse.com/), [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://www.redhat.com/products/enterprise-linux/), [Oracle Linux](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/linux/overview/index.html), [Scientific Linux](https://www.scientificlinux.org/), [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/), etc. all fit the bill. [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/category/audience/enterprise-0) LTS versions and their derivatives could also qualify.

If you mean distributions where you can sign a support contract, Red Hat EL and Suse Enterprise Linux qualify, and I believe Canonical offers Ubuntu support contracts as well.

Mind you, this is not an exhaustive list.

Comment: Yes, Oracle offers support for their RHEL clone, and Canonical offers support for Ubuntu LTS. There are some third parties offering support for Debian and CentOS AFAIK.

Comment: @vonbrand That's what I thought. I didn't know about third parties that offered support for Debian/CentOS.